# Can I control a Z84 counter timer circuit with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, shift-register

[Link to pin description](http://www.z80.info/z80ctc.htm) and [to the Datasheet](http://www.google.com).

I'm thinking about connecting channel outputs to LEDs and control the clock with IO-Arduino or a 555: I would program it with a 595 register.

Can someone explain me why this is a bad idea?

Comment: Your datasheet link point to google.com

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it was a "bad" idea - pointless maybe, but not "bad". A good learning experience if nothing else.

Comment: can you confirm that the project above could work? i wouldn't like to burn or break something.

Comment: I can see no reason why it wouldn't work. As long as you generate the right signals to emulate the Z80 bus it'll be fine. Just remember the resistors on the LEDs.